# Getting "The linked document (UNID... cannot be found in the view (UNID ...)" Error Message

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, notesview

I'm getting the error message below:
[image]

Upon clicking the doclink which was being attached in the e-mail which was generated by me through clicking the send to managers button. I also tried using NotesURL instead of doclink:

```
Call rtitem.appendtext(emaildoc.Notesurl)
```

but the generated URL is different from the doclink. Below is the generated from the doclink itself.

**Generated NotesURL:**  notes://LNCDC@PHGDC/__48257E3E00234910.nsf/0/237B2549EEA393A948257E530042BA4A?OpenDocument

**Doclink:**  Notes://LNCDC/48257E3E00234910/28BD6697AB48F55348257E2D0006CF60/C9B0266FDC0D929E48257E530041D6F9

Can you please help? Below is my agent code.

```html
%REM
 Agent Send Email to Managers
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare
Dim s As NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim emaildoc As NotesDocument
Dim paydoc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Dim i As Integer
Dim view As NotesView
Sub Initialize
 Set s = New NotesSession
 Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
 Set view = db.GetView("Pending Claims")
 Dim addresses As NotesName
 Dim arrpem As Variant
 ReDim arrpem(0)
 Set paydoc = view.GetFirstDocument

 '// Store all PEM names in an array
 While Not(paydoc Is Nothing)
  ReDim Preserve arrpem(UBound(arrpem) + 1)
  arrpem(UBound(arrpem)) = paydoc.PeopleManager(0)
  Set paydoc = view.GetNextDocument(paydoc)

 Wend
 '// Remove all duplicate PEM names and empty entries in the array
 arrpem = FullTrim(ArrayUnique (arrpem))

 '// Loop the PEM names array
 ForAll pem In arrpem
  Set emaildoc = New NotesDocument(db)
  Set addresses = New NotesName(pem)
  If addresses.abbreviated <> "" Then
   emaildoc.SendTo = addresses.abbreviated
   emaildoc.Subject = "Leave Balances of your Direct Reports"
   emaildoc.Form = "Memo"
   Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem(emaildoc, "Body")
   Call rtitem.AppendText("Dear " & addresses.common & ",")
   Call rtitem.AddNewLine(2)

   '// Remove paydoc value which was used in the PEM names array
   Set paydoc = Nothing

   '// Get all documents that has matching PEM name in the view
   Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
   Set dc = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(addresses.Abbreviated, True)
   Set paydoc = dc.GetFirstDocument

   '// Append doc link of employee
   While Not(paydoc Is Nothing)
    Call rtitem.AppendText("Doc link of :" & paydoc.FMName(0) & " " & paydoc.LastName(0))
    Call rtitem.appenddoclink(emaildoc, "Link to Leave Balance of " & paydoc.FMName(0) & " " & paydoc.LastName(0))   
    Call rtitem.AddNewLine(1)
    Set paydoc = dc.GetNextDocument(paydoc)
   Wend

   '// Send email per PEM
   Call emaildoc.Send(False)
  End If
 End ForAll

 MsgBox "Emails successfully sent."

End Sub
```

Comment: you append the doclink of the email? is this right? Should yo not append the doclink of the  paydoc Document?

Comment: You know what, you are a savior. Thank you! It works fine now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doclink is pointing back to the document you've created in memory for your email. When sent, that document no longer exists in the original database.

Change your code to be:

```
Call rtitem.appendtext(paydoc.Notesurl)
```